# is if elseif elseif possible vs if else ?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am newbie in php and I got really confused my code seems right and it works but not completely. I am trying to implement a translation using session for users to implement some other function when the condition is called using if elseif elseif, do i need to use  hain if-statements with if else else or is it possible like i did at first.

```
<?php

if ($_GET['lang']=='fr') { 
include('fr.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang']='fr';
} 


elseif ($_GET['lang']=='en') { 
include('gb.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang']='en';
}

elseif ($_GET['lang']=='it') { 
include('it.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang']='it';
}

elseif ($_SESSION['lang']=='fr')
{
include('fr.php');
}

elseif ($_SESSION['lang']=='en')
{
include('gb.php');
}

elseif ($_SESSION['lang']=='it')
{
include('it.php');
}

else
{
include('fr.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask. Not the slightest clue.

Comment: What you have posted is perfectly valid code in PHP. It's not the best approach (see Oli's answer), but it's perfectly valid nevertheless.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a switch statement for a neater code look:

```
switch($_SESSION['lang']) {
    case 'it':
        include(..);
        break;
    case 'en':
        include(..);
        break;

    etc..
}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Sorry my question was not very clear it's very hard to explain, I am already confused and it's difficult to me to be specific in english, Thank you for your answer so if i get it right the switch structure is a chain similar of elesif statement but more like a chain. I will have a look at the manual thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed here is that there's a lot of repeated code and what is essentially doing a look-up from multiple places.  If you restructure your code, you can do away with much of the complexity.  Here's the same thing done in a far simpler manner:

```
<?php

define('DEFAULT_LANG', 'fr');
$lang_inc = array(
    'fr' => 'fr.php',
    'en' => 'gb.php',
    'it' => 'it.php',
);

session_start()

if ($_GET['lang'] && array_key_exists('lang', $_GET)) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
} elseif ($_SESSION['lang'] && array_key_exists('lang', $_SESSION)) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} else {
    $lang = DEFAULT_LANG;
}

$lang_file = $lang_inc[$lang];
include($lang_file);

$_SESION['lang'] = $lang;
```

Comment: Thanks i was trying to implement it using arrays but it didn't work at first since you gave me the way now i will try it again like you did, thanks a lot and again sorry for not being very clear. I didn't now you can format it like this: if ($_GET['lang'] && array_key_exists('lang', $_GET)) {

Comment: My PHP is a big rusty, I think the proper way to write that might be `if( isset($_GET['lang']) && array_key_exists(...` to see if the value exists.  The idea is still the same.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers above i managed to get it worked now and it really helped me to understand the structure. The error didn't even came from this code but from another page related called menulang.php that i crated to call the sessions "I am noob I now .." but now i will try yours to have less repeated code and have it cleaner. And thanks for the resources you shared.

Answer (score 0):

When using sessions, you always have to call `session_start()`, whether you're initializing the session or just resuming it, so take it out of your statements and put it on top of your page. Furthermore, I don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve or whatever fails.

Comment: ok now i think got it so it should start always session_start();if ($_GET['lang']=='fr') { 
include('fr.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang']='fr';
}

Comment: Yes, so why don't you place it above your if/switch-statement? That way, you don't have to repeat it for each case.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did first but since it didn't change anything i was sure it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a need for if/else or switch since all you are doing is including a file which the dynamic part of the name is already defined in the language variable.

You also shouldn't need to reset $_SESSION['lang'] unless $_GET['lang'] is explicitly defined.

This would be more efficient and less than half the code used with if/else or switch conditionals based on the lang value.

```php
<?php
session_start();

// Only set $_SESSION[$lang] if it is not set
// or if $_GET['lang'] is explicitly defined
if (isset($_GET['lang']) || !isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {

    // Array of allowed languages
    $allowed = array('fr', 'en', 'it');

    // Set fr to default if lang isn't defined or not allowed
    $_SESSION['lang'] = isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], $allowed) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'fr';
}

// dynamically include file
include($_SESSION['lang'] . '.php');
```

Comment: Thank you this is a very good way too much simpler than what i did.